# How to correctly use kpfonts with classicthesis as both main and math font?

Tags: classicthesis, kpfonts

I want to use `kpfonts` with `classicthesis` both as the main font and as the math font. But I am not sure how to do it. When I use it, the error that I get is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/kpfonts.sty:588: LaTeX Err
or: Command `\mathscr' not defined as a math alphabet.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.588 ...lphabet{\mathscr}{boldsf}{U}{jkpsyd}{bx}{n}
```

When I press enter on this error about three times, the document compiles and produces a pdf but it uses the default Computer Modern font, not `kpfonts`. (See the screenshot below). If I comment the `kpfonts` I get the default Tex Gyre Pagella whcih is default of `classicthesis`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}           


\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: reverting to computer modern as the default font]

Comment: I get no error and the document is typeset with Kp fonts.

Comment: I get no error either. Show the complete log-file of your example. Oh, you are using xelatex?

Comment: I was using LuaLaTeX when I got this error. With pdflatex there is no error. XeLaTeX gives another bunch of errors `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty:19 9: Package fontspec Error: The font "DejaVu Sans Mono" cannot be found.` + the `mathscr` error above. Does one compile it with pdflatex only?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is pdflatex only, so if you want to use an unicode engine you should remove it. Beside this: classicthesis sets up lots of font stuff, also for xelatex/lualatex so it can be used with the unicode engines. As it uses font names and not file names you will have to adapt your font config settings to use it with xelatex on a linux system.

Comment: How does one adapt the font config settings (I am using a Mac)?